# Error when i am running `npm i` : code ENOLOCAL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

```
npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL
npm ERR! Could not install from "node_modules\react-navigation\react-native-tab-view@github:react-navigation\react-native-tab-view" as it does not contain a package.json file.
```

Comment: Check your path where you're running `npm i` it should be the root of your directory and I should have `package.json`

Comment: Check that you are running your command from the directory where is the `package.json`

Comment: still not working